# install proxmox from usb device error

Tags: kvm, proxmox

I try to install Proxmox using a USB, and when I click to install, I see the next error:

```
testing cdrom /dev/sr0
umount: can't umount /mnt: Invalid argument
testing again in 5 seconds
```

Finally:

```
no cdrom found - unable to continue (type exit or CTRL-D to reboot)
```

I prepare the USB using ImageUSB in Windows, and it does have the previous fail, then I try to prepare in Ubuntu using `dd if=pve-cd.iso of=/dev/XYZ bs=1M`, I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Please add more information: how did you prepare this usb? what a version? etc

Comment: Okey @ValeriySolovyov I have update the question

Answer (score 2):

For someone out there still having similar issue, use below method to create the installation media. That should help.

## Instructions for Windows

Download Etcher from https://etcher.io , select the ISO and your USB Drive.
If this doesn’t work, alternatively use the OSForensics USB installer from http://www.osforensics.com/portability.html

## Instructions for GNU/Linux

You can simply use dd on UNIX like systems. First download the ISO image, then plug in the USB stick. You need to find out what device name gets assigned to the USB stick (see below). Then run:

```
dd if=proxmox-ve_*.iso of=/dev/XYZ bs=1M
```

**Note**: Be sure to replace /dev/XYZ with the correct device name.
**Caution**: Be very careful, and do not overwrite the hard disk!

Instructions from: https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Install_from_USB_Stick

Comment: Thank you! This is obviously, but I use another program for "iso-to-flash" and get error, too...